# How to use PorterStemmer function with a list of words

Tags: python, tkinter, porter-stemmer

```
def stem(word):
    global c_bot
    stemArray=[]
    stemArrayRan=[]

    conn = sqlite3.connect('userData.db')
    c=conn.execute('SELECT sensation from symptoms')
    sympsToStem=c.fetchall()

    sympToStem=''

    for sympToStem in sympsToStem:
        stemArray.append(sympToStem)
    #print("hello",list(sympToStem))
    print("*********")
    #print("stemmed finale",stemmer.stem(word.lower()))
    for h in range(len(stemArray)):
        counter=0
    print(list(stemArray[h]))
    word=list(stemArray[h])
    print("newfound",word)


    print("stemm it",stemmer.stem(word.lower()))



word=''
sentence=''
#sentence=c_bot.get()

#main()
    
tryy=stem(word)
```

I'm not sure why the function doensn't let me pass the variable 'word' as a list, but does anyone know how I can get it to stem individual words from a user input into a sqlite3 database?

This is the error:

line 76, in stem
print("stemm it",stemmer.stem(word.lower()))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

#######

```
def submitChatbot():
    global c_bot
    # Create a database or connect to one
    conn = sqlite3.connect('userData.db')
    # Create cursor
    c = conn.cursor()

    # Insert Into Table
    c.execute("INSERT INTO symptoms VALUES (null,:c_bot)",
            {
                                'c_bot': c_bot.get().lower() 
                                
            })
    #Commit Changes
    conn.commit()
    # Close Connection 
    conn.close()

    # Clear The Text Boxes
    c_bot.delete(0, END)


def stem(word):
    global c_bot
    stemArray=[]
    stemArrayRan=[]

    conn = sqlite3.connect('userData.db')
    c=conn.execute('SELECT sensation from symptoms')
    sympsToStem=c.fetchall()

    sympToStem=''

    for sympToStem in sympsToStem:
        stemArray.append(sympToStem)
    #print("hello",list(sympToStem))
    print("*********")
    #print("stemmed finale",stemmer.stem(word.lower()))
    for h in range(len(stemArray)):
        counter=0
    print(stemArray[h])
    word=stemArray[h]
    print("newfound",word)


    print("stemm it",stemmer.stem(word))
```

Comment: It's obvious why you're getting that error: two lines earlier, you assign a list to `word`. Lists don't have a `lower()` method. What are you trying to do there?

Comment: @kindall I tried to break down the sentence that the user types into a separate list e.g. "I have a cold" to [I] [have] [a] [cold], but I that didn't work either?

Comment: I meant, what are you trying to do with the `lower()` call. Maybe you want to do that *before* you split the string?

Comment: @kindall The library won't let me execute that statement without the lower() method. That's the annoying part.

Comment: libraries can't tell what methods you've executed on a value you've passed to them; they only see the value. do you mean that the library requires that these strings be lower case? In that case, do as I suggested and lowercase the string before you split it.

Comment: @kindall Hmm I did that and now it says there is a tuple error: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower'